# How can I fill a Structure with values quickly?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am using Visual studios 2013 with Standard C.

My program takes four lines to put 
`{"Analysis 1", "AN 1", 0, 0.0667}` in `Fach[0]`.

I don't want to waste so many lines to fill this Array.

Is there a better way to put this four lines into one?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sFach
{
    char Mod[40];       //Modulbezeichnung
    char Ab[5];         //Abkürtzung
    int Note;           //Note
    double Gew;         //Gewichtungsfaktor
};

int main()
{
    struct sFach Fach[31];

    strcpy(Fach[0].Mod, "Analysis 1");
    strcpy(Fach[0].Ab, "AN 1");
    Fach[0].Note = 0;
    Fach[0].Gew = 0.0667;

    strcpy(Fach[1].Mod, "Algebra");
    strcpy(Fach[1].Ab, "AL");
    Fach[1].Note = 0;
    Fach[1].Gew = 0.0889;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make the code readable and easy to maintain; it is not a waste of code lines.

Comment: How is the lines of code something takes relevant? If you want to fill a struct with 4 members, you have to write 4 lines to do it. And even if you could somehow contrive a way not to, how would that be of any use?

Comment: Use a compound literal or initialiser with designated initialisers.

Comment: The Problem is that there are 31 lines in this Array, so it will take about 3 pages.

Comment: Shoudln't data like this come from a file rather than be hard-coded in the program?

Comment: Then make a function that passes the 4 values in, and have the function do the strcpy and assignment.   It doesn't make it 'faster' though.

Comment: If the entreis are different, how do you think the computer should know what you want to store? Clairvoyance will become standar**d** with post-quentum computers only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can initialise the whole array when you define it:

```
struct sFach Fach[] = {
    {"Analysis 1",      "AN1",  0,  0.0667},
    {"Algebra",         "AL",   0,  0.0889},
    {"Kunst 1",         "K1",   0,  0.1},
    {"Kunst 2",         "K2",   0,  0.1},
    {"Kunst 3",         "K3",   0,  0.1},
    {"Heimatkunde",     "HK",   0,  0.05},
    ...
};
```

The outer braces denote the array. You can leave out the dimension if you initialise the array; otherwise the remaining array entries are zero.

The inner braces denote the structs. If you are feeling verbose you can use designated initialisers as Jack has shown you.

If you want to assign whole structs after initialisation, you have to use the compound literal as shown by Basile.

Comment: I would recommend this option too, as it is by far the most readable.

Answer (score 8):

In C99 you have designated initializers, and also compound initializers (but I don't remember if they are an extension or supported by standard):

```
struct sFach
{
    char Mod[40];       //Modulbezeichnung
    char Ab[5];         //Abkürtzung
    int Note;           //Note
    double Gew;         //Gewichtungsfaktor
};

int main()
{
    struct sFach foo = { .Mod = "foo", .Ab = "bar", .Note = 10, .Gew = 10.0 };   
    struct sFach foo2 = { "foo", "bar", 10, 10.0 }; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But please note that this is not necessarily any better than the original code. I personally find this somewhat harder to read, mainly because of the single line formatting. In my opinion, splitting up the initializer list in 4 lines would improve readability.

Comment: I personally find this quite readable, so taste is taste. In addition to this I just answered what he asked for. He has a brain and he's able to choose what's suitable for him, we shouldn't judge taste, just provide solutions. Personally, capitalized fields for `struct` doesn't make any sense for example.

Answer (score 1):

With a recent (C11 conforming) compiler, you might try:

```
Fach[0] = (struct sFach){"Analysis 1","AN 1",0,0.667};
```

and so on for the next entries...

<sup>(an optimizing compiler would make that code quite efficient)</sup>

Another possibility would be to write some script (e.g. in [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), in Python, etc...) which would parse some data file and generate (from that data file) some `initialize_Fach.inc` file containing lines like above, and just add `#include "initialize_Gach.inc"` in your C code. Of course, you'll need to modify your build process (e.g. improve your `Makefile` or perhaps some Microsoft `.vproj` thing).

Don't forget that C code, in particular for initialization, can be generated by something else.